# What I must look into when porting big project from MySQL into Oracle?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, oracle

So I have lots  DB tables. I need to port my DB into Oracle. I have no problems on MySQL but must port onto oracle. so what are main tips&trics when going oracle from mysql?

Comment: So... 15+ tables with 6+ columns per table is a "big project" ?!?

Comment: I've seen databases where the tables and views were more than one thousand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the opportunity to read some documentation:

Oracle Concepts Guide

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/toc.htm

Oracle and MySQL Compared

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm

Answer (score 2):

On top of what ObiWanKenobi has referenced (learning Oracle), Oracle's FREE SQL Developer can do the migration for you

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/omwb-getstarted-093461.html

and the homepage is
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html

Keep a note on the auto_increment column, oracle has sequences that must be associated to the insert (handled by the insert or via a trigger).  the migration wizard should take care of these for you - but make sure that your increments are still working!